# Why is mess used with article?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I looked in the Cambridge Dictionary and mess is an uncountable. 
I wonder why mess is used with 'a'?

> He makes **a** terrible mess when he's cooking.
>
> I look **a** mess

Comment: Have you tried looking up this word in a dictionary?

Comment: I've looked up it in the cambridge dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Mess" is countable; its plural is "messes".  For example:

"There is a mess upstairs in your room."

versus

"There are messes all over this house!"

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/mess   The dictionary says that mess is [S or U]. What do they mean?

Comment: Send me the link of this and I'll try to figure it out.  As of now, I don't know what it means.  I'm guessing the U means uncountable, but the S, I don't know.  It could mean that it's both countable and uncountable, but I'm not sure without a link.

Comment: Your dictionary in Russian is wrong.  It says the "S" means it is usually treated as a singular noun, which is true, but it can be treated as a plural in some cases (see above).  The "U" means uncountable; however, that's wrong; it can be counted.  Example: "There were three different messes that I had to clean up."

Comment: You are right! English and Russian versions are different.

Comment: You're welcome.  I am glad I could help.  Oh and congratulation on learning English so well when Russian is your native tongue.  The two languages are so vastly different that that is very difficult to do unless you have been around English as well since you were young.

Comment: @AlexeySubbota If you move your mouse over the 'S' and 'U' on a computer, it should give you explanations of what they mean.  Unfortunately, the dictionary's explanations are wrong; it says that *mess* cannot be used with *a(n)*, and yet the examples they give use *a(n)*.  Someone made a mistake while working on that entry :-(

Comment: @NicholasCastagnola: I don't know why it says "S or U" rather than "C or U" in the Cambridge dictionary, except that use in the plural is relatively rare (Oxford Living Dictionaries' entry for "mess" says "usually in singular"), and learners' dictionaries tend to exclude rarer uses.  In any case, you're quite mistaken to say the dictionary is wrong to say "U", because it says "**or** U".  There is no implication that "mess" is always an uncountable noun, only that it is sometimes used as such.

Answer (score 2):

What the Cambridge dictionary actually says **isn't** that it's uncountable, but that it's "S or U", i.e. sometimes it's a singular countable noun, and sometimes it's uncountable.

It doesn't allow for it being plural (which occasionally it is, in real life), so to that extent the dictionary is inaccurate (and sometimes learners' dictionaries exclude rare senses or uses) - but nor does it imply that it's always uncountable.

It is true that is often used as an uncountable noun ("a lot of mess", "some mess", "some more mess", "not very much mess").

It can also be used as a singular countable noun, as both you and Cambridge noted ("making a mess").

Finally, it is occasionally used in the plural.

[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mess) gives more than a hundred examples of the use of "mess" as a noun, and none of them are of the plural.

[Collins Learners' Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mess) divides its definitions of "mess" as a noun into four senses.  The first is marked as "singular", the next two as "variable" (meaning sometimes countable and sometimes uncountable), and the fourth as "usually singular".